# Symfony ORM Integrity constraint issue

Tags: symfony, orm

I am working towards the following setup;

An **Article** has many **Comments**

A **Comment** has only one **article**

At the minute I am successful in not allowing a user to insert a comment into the database which is linked to an Article_Id which does not exist...

The problem comes when I try to print out the table via an inner join. I am receiving the error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: Article
```

Here is the code in my controller

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Article');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->innerJoin('a.comments','c')
        ->where('a.title LIKE :phrase')
        ->setParameter(':phrase','hello')
        ->getQuery();
```

and here are the entity classes - Any help greatly appreciated.

**Article Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
*/
class Article {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $title;


 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="Article") << ERROR HERE I BELEIVE
 */
protected $comments;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $title
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comments;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $comments
 */
public function setComments($comments)
{
    $this->comments = $comments;
}
```

}

**Comment Entity**

```
  <?php

 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use AppBundle\Entity\Article;


 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
  class Comment {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=300)
 */
protected $text;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="article", inversedBy="comment")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $article_id;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getText()
{
    return $this->text;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $text
 */
public function setText($text)
{
    $this->text = $text;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getArticleId()
{
    return $this->article_id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $article_id
 */
public function setArticleId($article_id)
{
    $this->article_id = $article_id;
}

}
```

Comment: you should also initialize your `comments` as `ArrayCollection` in Article's `__construct` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 little mistakes in your entities.

You can correct them this way:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 */
class Article
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
     */
    protected $comments;
}
```

and:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
class Comment
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $article;
}
```

Here's what I changed:

- `mappedBy="Article"` →  `mappedBy="article"` (it's the other's entity property name, without accent)
- `protected $article_id;` → `protected $article;` (your property is not the id, but an entity)
- `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="article", inversedBy="comment")` → `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments")` (it is the `comments` property you have in your `Article` entity (with as "s"), and the target entity has an uppercase A

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you so much for your time it is much appreciated. Also to add, I also had     * @ORM\Column(type="integer") on the $article property in Comment.php, because of this it was not reading my ManyToOne and JoinColumn